# Regex not firing on user form

Tags: javascript, regex

My Regex for email does not seem to be working, it does not fire,

the validation on the form passes even if the user only inputs a single .

here is my code:

```
var a = ["txtTitle", "txtSurname", "txtEmail", "txtPostCode"];

$.each(a, function (index, value) {
    if (sMsg == "") {


        if ($("#" + value).val().trim() == "") {
            var sText = $('td:first', $($("#" + value)).parents('tr')).text();

            sMsg = "Please enter a " + sText;

            $("#" + value).focus();
        }
    }
});

if (sMsg == "") {
    if ($("#txtPhone").val().trim() == "" && $("#txtMobile").val().trim() == "") {
        sMsg = "Please enter a phone or mobile number";
        $("#txtPhone").focus();
    }
}

if (sMsg == "") {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (!regex.test($("#txtEmail").val())) {
        sMsg = "Please enter a valid email address";
    }
}

break;
```

Comment: In the last if - did you forget the backslash before `.`? `[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]`

Comment: Where does "sMsg" come from? Does it contain a string? (You should always use `===` instead of `==`)

Comment: @maja: No backslash is necessary here. Within a character class, `.` only matches a dot.

Comment: regex seems to be fine.. mystery is behind sMsg .. pls make it clear.. where it comes from

Comment: @SonyGeorge sMsg is a string, i have now resolved this, turns out there was a primary validation on the email field to check whether it contains a value, i simply removed this and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have now resolved this, turns out there was a primary validation on the email field to check whether it contains a value, i simply removed this and it worked

amended this line:

```
var a = ["txtTitle", "txtSurname", "txtEmail", "txtPostCode"];
```

to

```
var a = ["txtTitle", "txtSurname","txtPostCode"];
```